# What exactly is the function of Callback URL in a Shopify app?

Tags: plugins, callback, shopify

This is the setting in green on the screenshot:

[image]

One function I see on the config pages is the setting below. I'm sure it applies because updating its value changes what's displayed for Callback URL.

```
Application URL (required)

When a merchant clicks on the app banner from their store admin,
we will redirect them to this URL.
```

Additionally, [here's](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/app-callback-url-roles-documentation-improvements-required-184719) a longer post on this topic, but the author is himself unsure.

Many thanks!

Comment: is the complete url index file of your app that `shopify` execute to install

Comment: It is, in fact the root url or main view of your Shopify app. Callback stands for: me, Shopify, after doing all the auths and checks if all are ok, where should I bring the merchant to?